# Is it correct to call a base class method on derived class objects when overloading output / input operator for derived class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, output, operator-overloading

Let's say we have those 2 classes "

```
class parent {
    
protected:
    float pr;
    
public:
    
     /// constructors, copy constructors, operator= overloading ...
     
     float get_pr() const
     {
         return pr;
     }
     
     friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& pout, const parent &obj1)
     {
         pout << obj1.get_pr() << '\n';
         return pout;
     }

};

class child: public parent {

protected:
    int age;
    
public:
    
     /// constructors & copy constructors using base class constructors, operator= overloading ...
     
     int get_age() const
     {
         return age;
     }
     
     friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& pout, const child &obj2)
     {
         pout << obj2.get_pr() << '\n';
         pout << obj2.get_age() << '\n';
         return pout;
     }

};
```

As you can see , in child class, at operator<< overloading code, i'm calling a method from base class. The program works but for me it dosn't feel right to call that method on obj2 ( which is a derived class object and it don't have a methot like get_pr() in its class). Would it still work if i had dynamic allocated memory in base class instead of that float pr?

Is there another way to do something like that or this is the only way ?

Comment: Can you show your main function in which you make the calls please?

Comment: What you are doing is correct.  A derived is a base, so it's fine to call base class functions from a derived class object

Comment: You could call base operator from child operator (`pout << static_cast<Base&>(*this);`), but in case of output this is a very strong relation. Any change in Base operator could break the way Child outputs, so the way you did it seems better to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's the basic idea of inheritance. `child` **is a** `parent` and therefore has a method `float get_pr() const`. So it's totally fine to call a base class method from a derived class.

A derived class (`child` in your case) inherits everything from it's `parent` class and can access every public and protected member of it.